# Obtain unread Outlook messages using O365 library

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook

I am building a small program to resend email from one outlook account to others, in Python.
After doing some research, I found the [O365 library](https://pypi.org/project/O365/).

I have managed to log in, and now I am building a query to obtain the unread messages. Based on the documentation, the filtering is using Open Data Protocol (OData).

```py
from O365 import Account

credentials = ('client_id', 'secret')
scopes = ['scopes_selected']

account = Account(credentials) #Login

mailbox = account.mailbox() #access mailbox

inbox = mailbox.inbox_folder() #access inbox folder
query = mailbox.new_query().on_attribute('isRead').equals('false') #get unread messages
for message in inbox.get_messages(query=query):
    print(message)
```

The error I get is:

```
Client Error: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?%24top=25&%24filter=isRead+eq+%27false%27 | Error Message: Invalid filter clause
```

I am aware that the URL the library creates is not correct, maybe because 'isRead' is not an attribute, but I have not managed to discover what it is.

Also, if I use the Graph tool offered by [Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), this query works:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=isRead eq false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to discover the error. Since the attribute I am filtering on is a boolean, I must use `True` or `False`after equals, not a string like `'false'` or `'true'`.

The correct way to do this query would be:

`query = mailbox.new_query().on_attribute('isRead').equals(False) #get unread messages`